# Biasing AC signal - which circuit is the best?

Tags: ac, dc, bias, shunt

I've seen a similar question asked earlier here:
[How do I bias an AC signal for sampling?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/150683/how-do-i-bias-an-ac-signal-for-sampling)

However, I have a **3 different circuits** and I am not sure which one works best!

**I have:** +-2V AC signal of varying frequency (5hz to 10kHz). It is biased around 0V.

**Objective:** Shunt this signal from 0V to 3V, so the **output is 1 to 5V signal** (the same +-2V just biased around 3V) like demonstrated here:

[image: Desirable outcome]

**Solution 1: Single Non-inverting Unity gain Op-Amps**
Here I cheated a little bit by increasing the AC signal from +-2v to +-4V, because the summing amp in this case forms a voltage divider [image: Non-inverting Unity gain Op amp]

**Simulation: Transient and AC**
[image]

**Solution 2: Two Inverting Unity gain Op-Amp in series**
By adding 2 inverting op amp in series, we can add to signals without "cheating" and scaling the input signals.
[image: 2 inverting op amps]

**Simulation: Transient and AC**
[image: inverting op amps sim]

**Solution 3: Three Non-Inverting Unity gain Op-Amps**
Why? Well, the AC signal source has some impedance, so to avoid any discrepancies on the summing op amp input, I thought it would be logical to put both the AC and DC components through unity gain buffers first...
[image]

**Simulation: Transient and AC**
[image]

All three circuits work and the output signal is in fact 1 to 5V in all three cases. Which solution is the best?

Answer (score 3):

I would say the first one, though a typically used solution is my schematic below. 
The other two are unnecessary complications

All you have to do is use a non-inverting buffer/voltage follower with a DC voltage divider on its input for centering the virtual ground level (of the AC signal) and place a capacitor on its input to separate the DC components between AC signal generator and the buffer input, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fetPX7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I take it as with this approach impedance matching would not be a problem? If for example the V1 impedance is unknown.

Comment: As long as the source impedance (Z_V1 + Z_C1) is reasonably small compared to R3. When the source impedance approaches R3 the AC signal gets attenuated.